# Python List Comprehension with two cycles

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, list-comprehension

I am a beginner in Python.

I learn list comprehension but my code is bad, because list comprehensions are wrong or missing:

I tried a lot of things, but results are generators or errors. Could you give me advice...?

Thank you.
Acer

```
import itertools as it
aT=list(it.permutations([4,3,3,0],3))
uT=list(set(aT))
# convert uniqueTimes list of tuples to list of lists
uT=[list(el) for el in uT]

uTt=[el[0]+el[1]+el[2] for el in uT] #It is wrong, I want universal list comprehension :-( when I change members of permutation, e.g.it.permutations([5,4,3,2,1],4))

uTs=[] #It is wrong too, I want universal list comprehension :-(
a=""
for m in range(len(uT)):
    for n in range(len(uT[m])):
        a+=str(uT[m][n])
    uTs.append(a)
    a=""

uTcombine=list(it.zip_longest(uTs,uTt)) #result as I expected, but the algorithm is "non comperhesion"

print(uT)
print(uTcombine)
```

from this (uT - list of lists, where each inner list is unique)

[[0, 3, 3], [3, 4, 3], [0, 3, 4], [3, 0, 3], [3, 4, 0], [3, 0, 4], [4, 0, 3], [4, 3, 3], [3, 3, 4], [3, 3, 0], [0, 4, 3], [4, 3, 0]]

I need that (uTcombine - list of tuples, where first in tuple is [0,3,3] => '033' and second is sum of list's items [0,3,3] => 6

[('033', 6), ('343', 10), ('034', 7), ('303', 6), ('340', 7), ('304', 7), ('403', 7), ('433', 10), ('334', 10), ('330', 6), ('043', 7), ('430', 7)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use existing functions from the standard library instead of writing your own where possible:

```
uT = [(''.join(map(str, el)), sum(el)) for el in uT]
```

In this case:

`''.join(map(str, el))` converts the permutation to the string representation you wanted `(0, 3, 3, )` -> `'033'` by first coverting each item to string (using `map(str, el)`), and then joining the strings.

`sum(el)` summarized the permutation `(0, 3, 3, )` -> `6`

Comment: So simply??? OMG. Thank you very much...
In my first version I had input to permutations as string ( permutations("3321",3) ) and I had the first comprehension right:
    uTs=list("".join(el) for el in uT)
But in the second part I lost like Gorro white dog in front of Tokyo:
    uTs = [sum(int(el)) for el in uT] # and a lot of next variations :-(, always with errors

Then I decide that the input will be list of numbers, not string. And this was the begining of my end :-( So thx one more time.

Please, let me known, what is solution, if input is string and uT=[[['0', '2', '2'],...]] ?

Comment: I got it... Similar:
    uTt=list(sum(map(int,el)) for el in uT)